# How can I specify an optional non-boolean parameter without default with argparse?

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I want to achieve the following

- parameter has type `float`
- if not passed on command line, the parameter name should not show up as a key in the `Namespace` obtained from the parser

So far I can only do this

```
parser.add_argument('--exponential-decay', type=float, required=False,
                    help='Decay parameter for exponential decay', metavar='GAMMA')
```

which causes `'exponential_decay': None` to appear in `vars(parser.parse_args())`. I could use that information as well, but I am curious whether this can be done.

I don't see anything in the `argparse` documentation covering this use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the default to `SUPPRESS`:

```
In [637]: parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [638]: parser.add_argument('--exponential-decay', type=float,
     ...:                     help='Decay parameter for exponential decay', metavar='GAMMA',
     ...: default=argparse.SUPPRESS);

In [640]: parser.parse_args([])
Out[640]: Namespace()
In [641]: parser.parse_args(['--exp=12'])
Out[641]: Namespace(exponential_decay=12.0)
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#default

> Providing default=argparse.SUPPRESS causes no attribute to be added if the command-line argument was not present:

Comment: To make this behavior on every option: `ArgumentParser(argument_default=argparse.SUPPRESS)`